# php.ini not found in location reported by phpinfo()

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, rackspace-cloud, php

We use an unmanaged Rackspace cloud server here at work. It's running Ubuntu 11.10. I wanted to install the gearman library and extension so I need to find the currently loaded `php.ini` file. Running `phpinfo()`, it says the file is at `/etc/php.ini`. Yet when I go to this directory in terminal, there is no file.

What's going on here and how can I start to sort this out?

**UPDATE**: I also just now ran `php --version` in terminal and it returns the wrong version displayed by phpinfo()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the webserver is running the site in a `chroot` environment, so that what is reported as `/etc/` by the webserver isn't the same `/etc/` that is used the machine as a whole.

As for the `php --version` reporting a different version, that likely means you have two separate versions of PHP installed. The web server is configured to use one (possibly again installed inside the `chroot` environment), and the machine as a whole is running an entirely different copy outside of the web server.

Read more about chroot here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot

Comment: I was just coming to that conclusion myself. I don't know anything about linux/unix so it didn't occur to me at first. I'll check into this now.

Comment: you might also want to ask this question on [ServerFault.com](http://serverfault.com/); you might get better quality assistance there.

Comment: Is there a way to change which version of PHP we use for our server? If you don't know I can go to serverfault.com

Comment: well, it ought to just be a case of installing the right version using Ubuntu's package manager, but I guess it depends what versions you've got and what version you want. eg If you're trying to downgrade to 5.2, you might have problems because that version isn't supported any more, so there might not be a package easily available for it. If the question is about the version in the chroot environment, I don't know enough about chroot to be happy giving an answer, so serverfault would be a better bet. I think I've answered the original question, but I wouldn't be comfortable going much further.